# Interactive map with a very large number of boundaries

Tags: maps, leaflet, mapbox, tilemill

I am trying to create an interactive map (where I can zoom in/out, show popup and info box) from Output Areas file: Output areas (E+W) 2011 Boundaries (Generalised, Clipped).
This file contains the digital vector boundaries for the 181,408 output areas (OA) in England and Wales.

Shapefile is ~80MB, geojson is ~210MB and topojson ~39MB (simplified). There is nothing more I can do to lower to size of the topojson. I have been trying to create a leaflet map, but the file is still far too large to load in a browser. I have also followed [this tutorial](http://www.minnpost.com/data/2012/03/how-we-built-same-day-registration-map) on creating map with my own tiles using TileMill, Leaflet and Wax. Unfortunately, the tiles generated for a reasonable zoom range are still > 100GB.

Does anyone know how I could load the boundaries and still be able to zoom in/out? Possibly using open-source technology?

Answer (score 2):

The TileMill output should not be 100GB. Are you sure you are limiting both the bounding box and the zoom range for the export? Check out http://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/crashcourse/exporting/

Comment: I was setting the zoom range, but not the bounds! This reduces the size considerably. Thank you for the tip.